# Error parsing yaml file for Google App Engine Cron jobs

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, yaml

I'm trying to set up some Cron jobs on Google App Engine. This is my cron.yaml file:

```
cron:
- description: "Progress update job"
  url: /cron-jobs/update-progress
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

When I try to deploy that, I get the following error:

```
$ appcfg.py update ./
06:52 PM Application: my-app-id; version: 1
06:52 PM Host: appengine.google.com
Error parsing yaml file:
Missing required value 'schedule'.
  in "./cron.yaml", line 3, column 1
```

I copied the cron.yaml almost exactly from the [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron), so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Edit: It works now, and don't know what's different. Retyped the exact same file, and now it works. Maybe, since I copy-pasted originally.

Comment: Once thing that stood out was the quotes around "Progress update job", which aren't present in the doc you cited. Looking a my cron.yml's, none of my descriptions are quoted strings. I don't see why that'd matter, but yaml can be finicky. It's worth a quick try.

Comment: I actually had it without quotes before, and that didn't work either. Just tried again, same thing. One thing I've been wondering about is that I pass all my requests into a single `main.py`, and don't have a separate handler/ webapp2 for Cron jobs like they do in the example. But I don't think that should make any difference, right?

Comment: Handlers are downstream of parsing `cron.yml`. Any problems in handlers are unrelated. This one's weird, also because line 3 looks fine. Is that your entire `cron.yml`, or a snippet?

Comment: That was the whole file. But now it seems to be fixed after I re-typed it all, and I haven't been able to replicate it since. Really weird.

Comment: Leon, did you copy/paste the original code from the web?  Sometimes, you can get a stubborn, hard-to-spot illegal character or spaces that way.

Comment: Yeah @GAEfan I copied it from the App Engine docs. I'm guessing that was the problem then.

Comment: Would be interesting/fun experiment to go copy it again and see if it recurs, so we get an answer here.

Comment: @GAEfan same thing. Guess that was it.

Comment: Have the same issue. Have you eventually resolved this issue?